# Javascript dictionary within dictionary is undefined

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I'm receiving a response from a server that is a dictionary that has within it another dictionary. The problem is that the inner dictionary is undefined. How do I define this dictionary?

Here's my code

```
$.ajax({url : destination_url, type : type, data : msg_Json, success : function(result){

                    console.log("Result: " + result);
                    var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                    var message;
                    console.log("Message type: " + obj.messageType);

                    if (obj.messageType == "LOAD"){
                        console.log("game state: " + obj.game_state);
                        message = {messageType : "LOAD", gameState : obj.game_state};
                        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, "*");
```

Here's what the console prints out:

```
Result: {"messageType": "LOAD", "gameState": {"playerItems": ["A rock", "A rock", "A rock"], "score": 40}}
Message type: LOAD
game state: undefined
```

Comment: It's clearly `obj.gameState`, not `obj.game_state`

Comment: Well that's embarassing

Answer (score 1):

well... game_state.. gameState.
One is snake case and the other one is camel case..?